# how to change the order of factor plot in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

My data looks like this:

```
m=pd.DataFrame({'model':['1','1','2','2','13','13'],'rate':randn(6)},index=['0', '0','1','1','2','2'])
```

I want to have the x-axis of factor plot ordered in [1,2,13] but the default is [1,13,2].

Does anyone know how to change it?

**Update**:
    I think I have figured it out in the following way, but maybe there is a better way by using an index to do that?

```
sns.factorplot('model','rate',data=m,kind="bar",x_order=['1','2','13'])
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate on OS X with Python 2.7.6, I get the order that you want.

Comment: Use the `x_order` keyword argument.

Comment: @Ffisegydd, that would most likely be: `import seaborn as sb; 
sb.factorplot('model', 'rate', data=m)`. I got the OP intended order of `[1, 2, 13]` as well.

Comment: I figured out my problem. cuz i changed the type of the model to string that is why 11 will appear earlier than 2.   Thank you so much for all your help!!! :)  But actually I am still curious about x_order, do I have to specify an index to do that?

Comment: hi mwaskom thank you so much for your help! I figured it out in this way, please see the update but I am still curious the way using index to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your update to the post shows the correct way to do it, i.e. you should pass a list of `x` values to `order` in the order you want them plotted. The default for numeric data is to plot in sorted order, so if you have numeric values it's best to keep them as integers or floats instead of strings, so they will be in "natural" order.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html) it appears that the seaborn API has updated again, the argument `x_order` should be replaced by `order`:

```
sns.factorplot('model', 'rate', data=m, kind="bar", order=['1','2','13'])
```

Also, `factorplot` has been renamed and will be removed in future releases; it is replaced by `catplot`:

```
sns.catplot('model', 'rate', data=m, kind="bar", order=['1','2','13'])
```

Comment: Nope, it is `order` instead of `row_order`, `row_order` only works when you specify the `row` parameter, and it outputs each bar into its own figure

Answer (score 1):

As @Pablo wrote in his comment and @Archie correctly mentioned in their answer:

> `x_order` should be replaced by `order`

For those who came here looking for a **sort** solution for `kind="count"`, it is possible to do so:

`sns.catplot(x="model", data=m, kind="count", order=m.model.value_counts().index)`

It's because by default `value_counts` method will return descending sorted values by count.